# Need to perform ORDER by Twice

Tags: sql, informix, hsqldb

I want to sort according to date first and then if date is similar then according to id..How to do that in Informix/HSQL query?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC, FIELD2 ASC
```

A good tutorial on this [SQL ORDER BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-sql-tutorial/)

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
ORDER BY date, id;
```

Answer (score 4):

Does

```
[rest of query] order by date, id
```

work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this(adjusted to your needs):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datecol ASC, id ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from (select * from tablename order by col1) AS T order by col2
```

*(It's necessary to give an alias to the virtual table, hence "AS T")*

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from (select * from tablename order by col1) AS T order by col2
```

This works but is redundant and obtuse. Note the subquery (on "col1") becomes the secondary sort; the primary sort is the encompassing query. Some environments may require the "as T" aliasing of the subquery, but not all.

```sql
select * from tablename order by col2, col1
```

This does the same thing as above, with simple clarity

Or for a more realistic example:

```sql
select * from customers order by lastname, firstname
```