# MySQL double ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

I got a MySQL tablw which will store the contest participant informations.

Structure like

```
id   +   user_id    +   marks     +   date_added
-----+--------------+-------------+----------------------
1    |   24         |    30       |  2014-02-06 03:04:08
-----+--------------+-------------+----------------------
1    |   25         |    10       |  2014-02-06 13:04:08
-----+--------------+-------------+----------------------
1    |   26         |    14       |  2014-02-06 05:04:08
-----+--------------+-------------+----------------------
1    |   27         |    54       |  2014-02-06 21:04:08
```

From this I need to find out a winner .

ie the winner with maximum marks. In case of multiple candidate with max marks then it will be on first come basis.

Got many contest with thousands of datas

Can anyone please show me a hint ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to perform ORDER by Twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532599/need-to-perform-order-by-twice)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    `table name`
ORDER BY
    marks DESC, date_added ASC
LIMIT
    1
```

Replace `table name` though.